# Additional table slowing down mySQL execution time

Tags: mysql

I noticed that adding an additional table to the query, even if it is not used, slows down the execution greatly.
Originally, I had the following queries:

```
SELECT p.ID, c.description 
FROM potatoes pp,  plants p, cells c
WHERE pp.sampleID = p.id
AND p.cellSampleID = c.id
AND p.ID REGEXP "^A-11"
AND c.number = 1;
```

and

```
SELECT p.ID, c.description 
FROM potatoesNEW ppn,  plants p, cells c
WHERE ppn.sampleID = p.id
AND p.cellSampleID = c.id
AND p.ID REGEXP "^A-11"
AND c.number = 1;
```

Both of these take about 30 seconds to execute. I wanted to unite them into one query, so I used

```
SELECT p.ID, c.description 
FROM potatoes pp, potatoesNEW ppn, plants p, cells c
WHERE (pp.sampleID = p.id OR ppn.sampleID = p.id)
AND p.cellSampleID = c.id
AND p.ID REGEXP "^A-11"
AND c.number = 1;
```

There, the execution time suddenly took so long that I aborted the query after about 5 minutes.
I thought, the OR might be slowing the query down, but after I changed the query to the following:

```
SELECT p.ID, c.description 
FROM potatoes pp, potatoesNEW ppn, plants p, cells c
WHERE pp.sampleID = p.id
AND p.cellSampleID = c.id
AND p.ID REGEXP "^A-11"
AND c.number = 1;
```

it still took so long that I had to abort it after a few minutes. How can it be that just the mentioning of the additional table potatoesNEW slows down the query so much, although, when used in separate queries, both only take a few seconds?

Comment: This might be related to the storage engine you're using for example. If you are using `MyISAM` there will be a lock on the added table, while `InnoDB` will perform lock on rows instead when performing selects.

Comment: Since you seem to want a union of the two queries, use select ... `UNION` select ... The combination queries that you are using seems to start off with a Cartesian product. That has to take time, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to want any columns-results from either "potatoes" nor "potatoesNEW", but just want to check that the record from "plant" exists in either of them. You can do that directly in the SQL using `EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT p.ID, c.description 
  FROM plants p, cells c
 WHERE p.cellSampleID = c.id
   AND p.ID REGEXP "^A-11"
   AND c.`number` = 1
   AND (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM potatoes pp
                 WHERE pp.sampleID = p.id)
       OR
        EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM potatoesNEW ppn
                 WHERE ppn.sampleID = p.id)
       );
```

Or as I mentioned in a comment using `UNION`:

```sql
SELECT p.ID, c.description 
  FROM potatoes pp,  plants p, cells c
 WHERE pp.sampleID = p.id
   AND p.cellSampleID = c.id
   AND p.ID REGEXP "^A-11"
   AND c.`number` = 1;
UNION
SELECT p.ID, c.description 
  FROM potatoesNEW ppn,  plants p, cells c
 WHERE ppn.sampleID = p.id
   AND p.cellSampleID = c.id
   AND p.ID REGEXP "^A-11"
   AND c.`number` = 1
```

---

Note that `number` is a keyword, so it needs backticks.

---

You're using old `JOIN` syntax:

```sql
SELECT p.ID, c.description 
  FROM plants p, cells c
 WHERE p.cellSampleID = c.id
```

New syntax will look like this:

```sql
SELECT p.ID, c.description 
  FROM plants p
  JOIN cells c ON p.cellSampleID = c.id
```

Making the `EXISTS` SQL into:

```sql
SELECT p.ID, c.description 
  FROM plants p
  JOIN cells c ON p.cellSampleID = c.id
 WHERE p.ID REGEXP "^A-11"
   AND c.`number` = 1
   AND (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM potatoes pp
                 WHERE pp.sampleID = p.id)
       OR
        EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM potatoesNEW ppn
                 WHERE ppn.sampleID = p.id)
       );
```